# c# Serial port close

Tags: c#

Already use this class, in `Form1` and `Form2`

```
public class DataInput
{
    public event Action<string> DataReceived;

    private readonly SerialPort mySerialPort;

    public DataInput(string portName)
    {
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort();
        mySerialPort.PortName = portName;
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mySerialPort_DataReceived);
        mySerialPort.Open();
    }

    private void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string received = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();
        DataReceived?.Invoke(received);
    }
}
```

Now when i close `Form2` with `this.Close();` i need close the `Serial port` too.
Because when i opend the form again it says `Access to the port 'COM1' is denied.`

How can i close the port??

Comment: you use "mySerialPort.Open();" where is the "mySerialPort.Close();"

Comment: What is the problem to add `mySerialPort.Close();` in `Form's Closing` Event Handler?

Comment: no problem there, just i am new in c# so need little help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine @Ketan's solution and your code:

```
public class DataInput
{
    public event Action<string> DataReceived;

    ...

    public void Close()
    {
        if(mySerialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            mySerialPort.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In Form2:

```
private void Form2_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    dataInput.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close serial port connection. You can call `mySerialPort.Close()` in Form2 closing event as below:

```
private void Form2_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if(mySerialPort.IsOpen)
  {
    mySerialPort.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: the class i have it separate file and when i use this i get The name 'mySerialPort' does not exist in the current context

Comment: in Form2 i use             dataInput = new DataInput("COM9");
            dataInput.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;

Comment: You need a `Close` method in DataInput that calls the code from above. This Close method can then be called from Form2

Comment: yes, i need help add the close method in the class code above